# Update SQL for a 100 column row in a table based on another table with the name column names

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

One row in a table got mistakenly overwritten. I have a backup of the table and need to update a single row in the main table with the backup data. The trouble is that the table has almost 100 columns. Is there an easy way to do this in SQL Server so that I do not have to manually write out this:

```
set maintable.a = backuptable.a, 
    maintable.b = backuptable.b,......etc.
```

all the way up to the 100th column. I would think that SQL Server Management Studio could know that I want to update the fields with the same-named fields in the other table. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO MainTable
SELECT *
FROM BackUpTable
WHERE RowID = GoodRow

DELETE FROM MainTable
WHERE RowId = BadRow
```

Just insert the "good" row and delete the "bad" row.

If there is a PK constraint you can delete/insert in the opposite order.

It would also be wise to enclose this in a `TRANSACTION`.

Comment: What if the primary key is an identity column?  I'm getting the following error: "Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'members' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF."

Comment: If it's an `identity` then you need to use an explicit column list.  no way around it.

Answer (score 1):

In SSMS you can drag-n-drop the `columns` node in the Object Explorer to the Query window. It will generate a comma-separated string of all the columns.

Comment: +1 - Good point.  Would still be a PITA to write out the syntax for the update though

Comment: @JNK - So true. This is more convenient when used in an insert.

Answer (score 0):

```
> declare @aa varchar (max) set @aa = ''
> 
> select  @aa = 
>     (case when @aa = ''
>     then column_name
>     else @aa + coalesce(', ' + column_name+'= '+column_name, '')
>     end) from amicus.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'People' print @aa
```